# PHP - replace relative path with domain on page

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have html page like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js?1617644081"></script>
</body>
```

How can I replace it to be like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/assets/css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://example.com/assets/js/script.js?1617644081"></script>
</body>
```

Numbers after `assets/js/script.js?` change every refresh.

Comment: Search for `"assets/` and replace with `"https://example.com/assets/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, Using [heredoc](https://www.php.net/heredoc) and [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

```php
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js?1617644081"></script>
</body>
HTML;
$html = str_replace('assets/', 'https://example.com/assets/', $html);
echo $html;
/* Output:
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/assets/css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://example.com/assets/js/script.js?1617644081"></script>
</body>
*/
?>
```